# How to increase resolution

Tags: display, resolution

I have a Dell Inspiron 14R-N4010 laptop with Windows 7 64-bit installed.

The screen resolution is 1024 x 768 - how can I increase the resolution to 1280 x 800? I have "Generic PnP Monitor on Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" configured.

Comment: Install the driver for your display that is included with the machine on a CD or part of the recovery installation.

Comment: Easy. RTFM.  Will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Enter your service tag here [Dell Drivers and downloads](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen)  and download the drivers for your machine. Then install them. Should open up more resolutions after you are done.

Answer (score 1):

This following links are the 64-bit Windows 7 drivers/application for the possible videos card that came with your laptop. The first one is the Intel, on-board video card driver. The second is if you bought an upgrade to the ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 550v video card. You have one or the other.

If you do not know for sure, try the first one, and if you don't have the right hardware, it will probably tell you during the install. My bet is on this one though.

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R268991&SystemID=INSPIRON_N4010&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&deviceid=22753&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=3&catid=6&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=6&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=395844

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R297612&SystemID=INSPIRON_N4010&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&deviceid=25206&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=3&catid=6&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=6&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=446718